# SQL de tabelas com múltiplos relacionamentos

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

- Como seriam as representações SQL de criação e inserção correta das tabelas abaixo de forma que seja possível ter/armazenar o número total de vídeos de um gênero de forma que seja possível pegar, por exemplo, todos os filmes do usuário 1 que são do gênero 3?
- Selecionar os filmes de um gênero determinado (o gênero é passado pelo nome e não pelo id).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE TABLE usuario(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
data_nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE filme(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
duracao INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE genero(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE rel_usuario_filme( 
id_usuario INTEGER NOT NULL, 
id_filme INTEGER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id_usuario, id_filme), 
CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_filme FOREIGN KEY (id_filme) REFERENCES filme(id));

CREATE TABLE rel_filme_genero(
id_filme INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_genero INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id_filme, id_genero),
CONSTRAINT fk_genero FOREIGN KEY (id_genero) REFERENCES genero(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_filme FOREIGN KEY (id_filme) REFERENCES filme(id));
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54230/discussion-on-question-by-ricardo-sql-de-tabelas-com-multiplos-relacionamentos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A estrutura que tens neste momento permite responder às tuas duas questões:

- "armazenar o número total de vídeos de um gênero de forma que seja possível pegar, por exemplo, todos os filmes do usuário 1 que são do gênero 3?"

Número de filmes para cada um dos géneros:

```
select g.nome, count(rel.id_filme)
from genero g
left join rel_filme_genero rel
   on rel.id_genero = g.id
group by g.nome
```

Todos os filmes do usuario 1 que são do género 3:

```
select f.nome
from filmes f
inner join rel_filme_usuario relfu
  on relfu.id_filme = f.id
inner join rel_filme_genero relfg
  on relfg.id_filme = f.id
where relfu.id_usuario = 1
  and relgf.id_genero = 3
```

"Selecionar os filmes de um gênero determinado (o gênero é passado pelo nome e não pelo id)":

```
select g.nome, f.nome, f.duracao
from genero g
inner join rel_filme_genero relfg
   on relfg.id_genero = g.id
inner join filmes f
   on f.id = relfg.id_filme
where g.nome = 'Comedia'
```

Inserir o filme e depois a informação dos géneros. Eu executaria isto numa transacção:

```
start transaction

insert into filme (nome, duracao) 
values ('Titanic', 120);
set @filme_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
insert into rel_filme_genero (id_filme, id_genero) 
select @filme_id, g.id 
from generos g
where g.nome in ('comedia', 'romance'); 

commit
```

Sugiro apenas que no teu fluxo de processo garantes sempre que o conteúdo da tabela Género seja controlado por ti e não permitas a inserção indiscriminada de valores. Até porque o universo de valores para o Género não é muito grande.
Desta forma acredito que possas manter a estrutura actual de tabelas.

Comment: O que seria `from genero g`? você esta criando um alias pra tabela genero? se sim em `select g.genero` suponho que deveria ser `g.nome` onde `nome` é o nome do genero

Comment: Sim, tens toda a razão. Editei a minha resposta de acordo com o teu comentário.

Comment: Simplifiquei agora um pouco a primeira instrução. Ela deve devolver para cada Genero na tabela Generos, o numero de filmes. Informação que pode ser obtida directamente na tabele rel_filme_genero. Sem necessidade de juntar tambem a tabela filmes.

Comment: a 1ª SQL esta retornado somente um genero e como resultado do cont a quantidade de registros da tabela rel_filme_genero, eu queria que retornasse uma linha pra cada genero sendo a primeira coluna o genero e a segunda a quantidade de filmes do genero.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique, podes ver a actualizacao, por favor. Ja agora, a base de dados é MySQL?

Comment: EStava escrevendo o comentario quando você atualizou a resposta, sim é mysql, testei a versão atualizada e retornou somente terror e o resultado do cont (56, numero de registros da tabela rel_filme_genero)

Comment: Ok, da forma como estava escrita apenas iria listar os generos se eles tivessem filmes associados. Actualizei outra vez. Assim, devera listar todos generos ainda que nao tenham filmes associados

Comment: ,@bruno funcionou, haveria como você criar um insert de um video e em seguida o insert de suas relações com seus gêneros (Comedia e Acao) usando os nomes dos generos?

Comment: `INSERT INTO filme (nome, duracao) VALUES ('Titanic', 120);` exemplo de insert de filme

Answer (score 2):

### Diagrama

O que eu entendi do seu problema:

[image: Diagrama de tabelas]

**Seria correto dizer então que**

- **1** usuário pode ter **1** ou **N** filmes
- **1** filme pode ter **1** ou **N** generos

**é possível ler ao contrário também**

- **1** genero pode estar em **N** filmes
- <strike>**1** filme pode estar com **N** usuarios</strike>. Na verdade acho que você quis dizer que **1** filme pode estar com somente **1** usuário, neste caso, sua regra de negócio tera que garantir este estado.

### Fazendo perguntas para o modelo de dados

**Como contar o número de filmes de um determinado gênero ?**

```
SELECT g.nome, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rel_filme_genero WHERE id_genero = g.id_genero) AS quantidade 
FROM genero g 
WHERE g.id_genero = 1 OR g.nome = "nomeDoGenero"
```

**Como contar o número de filmes do usuario de um determinado gênero ?**

```
SELECT usuario.nome, genero.nome, COUNT(*) AS quantidade FROM usuario 
LEFT JOIN rel_usuario_filme ON usuario.id_usuario = rel_usuario_filme.id_usuario 
LEFT JOIN filme ON rel_usuario_filme.id_filme = filme.id_filme 
LEFT JOIN rel_filme_genero ON filme.id_filme = rel_filme_genero.id_filme 
LEFT JOIN genero ON rel_filme_genero.id_genero = genero.id_genero 
WHERE usuario.id_usuario = 1 AND genero.nome = "Acao" 
GROUP BY usuario.id_usuario, genero.id_genero
```

**Como eu descubro a quantidade de filmes por genero?**

Dentro as varias formas possíveis, segue uma:

```
SELECT nome, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rel_filme_genero WHERE id_genero = g.id_genero) AS quantidade 
FROM genero g
```

[Você pode usar este modelo de dados simples que eu fiz no SQL Fiddle para testar](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4518/12)

Aproveitando, você pode trocar LEFT (que sempre dará preferencia pelos registros da esquerda) poin INNER para só retornar linhas de resultado casa haja registros de ambos os lados na hora de realizar a junção. [Nesta pergunta, tem mais detalhes sobre os tipos de  JOIN's](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/6448#6448)

Comment: Gostaria que a primeira SQL retornasse todos os generos junto com a quantidade de filmes de cada genero.

Comment: @RicardoHenrique editado. Tenho uma dúvida, este exemplo é apenas para estudo ou você pretende colocar programação no meio, por exemplo, você está com duvidas sobre como apresentar essas informações de formas mais simples em um sistema ? Se sim, a abordagem para montagem dos SQL's deveriam ser pensados de maneira diferente das que eu apresentei aqui.

Comment: ,@wryel são para estudos, mas há uma forma diferente? esta forma diferente é somente relativa a criação dos selects ou seria uma mudança completa inclusive no banco de dados?

Comment: Se você fosse programar os DAO's, para facilitar seu trabalho, provavelmente teria que usar uma das muitas opcoes para facilitar a manutebilidade e diminuir a complexidade do software. Se você quisesse carregar todas as informacoes em uma unica ida ao banco de dados, você provavelmente conseguiria, porem, o SQL ficaria gigante e ainda assim sucetivel à erros. A melhor abordagem seria por exemplo carregar o usuario, depois, fazer um metodo para carregar os filmes daquele usuario (selec bla from .. where id_usuario = ?) e depois dar um size() para descobrir o tamanho.

Comment: Assim, você consegueria reaproveitar esse mesmo método caso quisesse listar os filmes do usuario também. Esse tipo de problema iria começar a aparecer com a implementação e consequentemente a as duvidas de qual seria a melhor forma (o que agora não é escopo da sua pergunta).

Comment: .@wryel mas preciso do numero de registros previamente para criar a paginação da página.

Comment: Você pode trazer essa informações em uma única ida ao banco como eu disse e como você quer fazer, porem, observe que a "contagem" de registros, não é um atributo de um objeto (exceto se tivessemos falando de um relatorio). Você pode fazer, mas este agregado de informações não seria reutilizável. A menos que a justificativa seja por exemplo, não quero trazer 10.000 registros para fazer um size() em memória (afinal, no banco é menos custoso), você deveria preferir fazer um metodo listarFilmesPorUsuario() que retornasse todos os filmes e depois descobrir o tamanho por size.

Answer (score 1):

Para corrigir o problema de **relacionamento** vou passar seu script com as devidas alterações necessárias, tem um comentário já explicando o porque da alteração

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usuario;
CREATE TABLE usuario(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
data_nascimento DATE NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS filme;
CREATE TABLE filme(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
duracao INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS genero;
CREATE TABLE genero(
id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rel_usuario_filme;
CREATE TABLE rel_usuario_filme( 
id_usuario INTEGER NOT NULL, 
id_filme INTEGER NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id_usuario, id_filme), 
CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuario(id), 
CONSTRAINT fk_filme FOREIGN KEY (id_filme) REFERENCES filme(id));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rel_filme_genero;
CREATE TABLE rel_filme_genero(
id_filme INTEGER NOT NULL,
id_genero INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id_filme, id_genero),
CONSTRAINT fk_rel_fg_genero FOREIGN KEY (id_genero) REFERENCES genero(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_rel_fg_filme FOREIGN KEY (id_filme) REFERENCES filme(id));

ALTER TABLE `test`.`rel_filme_genero` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_rel_fg_filme`;
ALTER TABLE `test`.`rel_filme_genero` 
ADD COLUMN `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'id_filme e id_genero nao pode ser chave composta pois 1 filme pode ser comedia romantica por exemplo, entao as duas sao apenas chaves estrangeiras aqui' FIRST,
DROP PRIMARY KEY,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD INDEX `fk_rel_fg_filme_idx` (`id_filme` ASC);
ALTER TABLE `test`.`rel_filme_genero` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_rel_fg_genero`;
ALTER TABLE `test`.`rel_filme_genero` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rel_fg_genero`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_genero`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`genero` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rel_fg_filme`
  FOREIGN KEY (`id_filme`)
  REFERENCES `test`.`filme` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Para sua dúvida sobre o **total de filmes** do usuário 1 que seja do genero 3, a regra da forma normal diz para não armazenarmos informação que pode ser obtida através de calculo e/ou consulta ( não lembro o numero da regra e possivelmente não esta com estas palavras ) então o correto seria uma consulta que faça esse total p/ você

```
SELECT u.nome,
    (select sum(1) from rel_usuario_filme ruf, rel_filme_genero rfg where ruf.id_usuario=u.id and ruf.id_filme=rfg.id_filme and rfg.id_genero=3) as total_filmes
FROM usuario u
where 
    -- u.nome = 'joao' ou pelo id abaixo
    u.id = 1;
```